# Validate() Dynamically Added fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am adding fields into a form dynamically, and these fields are required.

Even when i call validate() again after creating the fields, they are not validated.

Any idea why?
Thanks

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/gzcypn1r/)**

HTML:

```
    <form action="" class="validate">
    <select id="A1" class="required" >
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
        <br>    <input type="submit" name="go" value="go" />
    </form>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(".validate").validate();

    $("#A1").on("change", function(){
       var A1 = $(this).val();
        if (A1=='1') {
            $("#A1").nextAll('select').remove();
            $('<select id="A11" class="required" >    <option value="">you selected 1, now select....</option>    <option value="1">11</option>    <option value="2">22</option></select>').insertAfter($(this));
            $(".validate").validate();
        } else if (A1=='2') {
            $("#A1").nextAll('select').remove();
            $('<select id="A22" class="required" >    <option value="">you selected 2, now select....</option>    <option value="1">1111</option>    <option value="2">2222</option></select>').insertAfter($(this));
            $(".validate").validate();
        } else {
            $("#A1").nextAll('select').remove();
        }

    });
```

Comment: You **cannot** call `.validate()` multiple times on the same `form`.  Once you call `.validate()`, the plugin is initialized and subsequent calls are ignored.

Comment: So how does one re-call the `validate()` function on newly generated fields?

Comment: You do not.  If you want to add/remove rules on any field including new ones, that's what the `.rules()` method was created for.  See documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

Comment: In your particular case, you are using the HTML5 `required` attribute on your new field, so the plugin automatically picks this up without using the `.rules()` method.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/gzcypn1r/2

Comment: interesting - thanks!

Comment: Also, your form is being selected by a class.  If you have more than one form with this class, you'll only be initializing the plugin on the ***first*** occurrence of a `form` containing this class.  If you need to initialize the plugin on multiple forms at the same time, you must use a jQuery `.each()`.

Comment: strange - i thought that it would apply to all elements of that class , like a regular class selector works?

Comment: Using `$(".validate")`, jQuery selects _every_ element with this class just as it's supposed to.  However, _this plugin_ will only take and use the _first_ matching element.  Wrap it within an `.each()` and it works fine.  Lots of examples here on SO of this.  The [docs mention this limitation too, however, it suggests a different solution](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#validating-multiple-forms-on-one-page).

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution: as soon as I add a 'name' atribute to the various fields - they are re-validated.

```
    <form action="" class="validate">
    <select id="A1" name="A1" class="required" >
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
        <br>    <input type="submit" name="go" value="go" />
    </form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/gzcypn1r/1/

Comment: It's a well known requirement of this plugin that every input element has a (unique) `name` attribute.  It's in [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#markup-recommendations) as well as the [tag's SO wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).